# Unknown Display on DP-3. Only one display present

Tags: drivers, display, bios, external-monitor, displayport

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS show a second unknown display, which is not actually present. I have tried every related solution with no success.

- I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
- I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 graphic card.
- I have nvidia-driver-470 installed.

Attempts:

- Clean install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Solutions involving `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- purging nvidia drivers and reinstalling.
- modifying grub file `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` for unknown display at `DP-1-3`

`xrandr` output:

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
> eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right > x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
> 1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93
> 1680x1050     59.95    59.88
> 1600x1024     60.17
> 1400x1050     59.98
> 1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
> 1280x1024     60.02
> 1440x900      59.89
> 1400x900      59.96    59.88
> 1280x960      60.00
> 1440x810      60.00    59.97
> 1368x768      59.88    59.85
> 1360x768      59.80    59.96
> 1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
> 1152x864      60.00
> 1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
> 1024x768      60.04    60.00
> 960x720       60.00
> 928x696       60.05
> 896x672       60.01
> 1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
> 960x600       59.93    60.00
> 960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
> 800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
> 840x525       60.01    59.88
> 864x486       59.92    59.57
> 800x512       60.17
> 700x525       59.98
> 800x450       59.95    59.82
> 640x512       60.02
> 720x450       59.89
> 700x450       59.96    59.88
> 640x480       60.00    59.94
> 720x405       59.51    58.99
> 684x384       59.88    59.85
> 680x384       59.80    59.96
> 640x400       59.88    59.98
> 576x432       60.06
> 640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
> 512x384       60.00
> 512x288       60.00    59.92
> 480x270       59.63    59.82
> 400x300       60.32    56.34
> 432x243       59.92    59.57
> 320x240       60.05
> 360x202       59.51    59.13
> 320x180       59.84    59.32

DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1024x768      60.00
800x600       60.32    56.25
848x480       60.00
640x480       59.94

DP-1-3 is the unknown monitor. I believe it is preventing me from using an external HDMI monitor.